# SharePoint 2013 HTTP 503 error

Tags: sharepoint

I have SharePoint 2013 ServicePack 1 on Windows Server 2012 R2. In administration panel I had error about multiple services running on one Administration account, so it redirected me to page where I chose service and assing new account (added in Active Directory). Then it give me a command to force restart IIS. After restart I get 503 error, so according to [this](http://www.brainbrushups.com/2013/07/solve-http-error-503-service-is.html) I started all applications, but when I'm trying to open Central Administration of Sharepoint i have still 503, after refreshing applications in IIS the Central Administration is stoped again. It stops when I'm trying to run it. How to get rid of that 503?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Changing users in IIS help

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the services are all running correctly via windows control panel

Comment: And where exactly I can check that?

Comment: Not in IIS but in Windows Control Panel... Administrator Tools... Services which gives a full list of services for your whole environment from SQL Server to IIS to Sharepoint services. The most important service as far as Sharepoint is concerned is the Timer service but there are many. Sharepoint is an extremely large and complicated beast! Each service needs to run as an account that has the correct permissions for the resources it needs to use.

Comment: Also looking in the Windows Event logs can point to where any issues may lie.